# why without display:none, css3 transition not working?

Tags: css

The code is from Bootstrap carousel, I wonder why without display:none, css3 transition not working? It should move from right to left.
Thanks! https://jsfiddle.net/25d3ga9j/11/

I want to remove .item{display:none}, and add visibility: hidden, then keep it working. It works in Firefox(transition-property: left),but not in Chrome(transition-property: transform;transform: translate3d...)
https://jsfiddle.net/zjmove/r8ejf5Lk/

```js
$('.item').addClass('next')
$('.item')[0].offsetWidth   // force reflow
$('.item').addClass('left')
```

```css
.item {
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  display: none;    //why with out display:none, transition not working?
}
.c {
  overflow: hidden;
}


.item {
  transition: transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.item.next {
  display: block;
  transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
  left: 0;
}

.item.next.left {
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="c">
  <div class='item'>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But it does move from right to left....

Comment: @LGSon Hi, in my broswer(chrome 57,firefox 47), without .item{display: none; }, it  not move(0.6s), it just appear quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a few things going on here, where the first is whether the first script line might run before the DOM is ready `$('.item').addClass('next')`

The second, there is no time for the first class to finish its transition until the second gets added, but a delay might solve that.

Either way, and based on whether which comes first (may vary between browsers), you can get different result.

The below sample shows how it should be set up when not using `display: none`, which by the way should be avoid if possible

```js
$(window).load(function() {

  $('.item').addClass('left')
  
});
```

```css
.c {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.item {
  transition: transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  perspective: 1000px;
  transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}

.item.left {
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="c">
  <div class='item'>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you LGSon,  the second line "$('.item')[0].offsetWidth" seems make the "first class to finish its transition" immediately. You code is working, but i need the "next" class, since the item also need move from left to right, when add class"prev right". The code is from Bootstrap carousel, I want remove display:none, and add visibility: hidden, then keep it working.

Comment: @zhengjie I showed why it didn't work, now you can add which ever class you need to have it go left/right or right/left.

Comment: @zhengjie If my answer helped, may I ask you to consider to accept it as well